# Tool for Search in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I am in search of a tool, with which I can organize my e-mail inbox!! It should search of course for e-mails, but it would be nice if I can also search for and in attachments, appointments, adresses etc. Beside this it also should be small and of course fast! ;)

I heard and read of several tool (xobni, copernic, WDS, Lookeen), but now wanted to know your opinions which would be the best...I am interested in all, no matter if freeware or not!

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a pretty poor response from the community! I too am in need of such a tool and would like to know which is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

use Google Desktop, it's perfect at searching Outlook and you can configure it to NOT index the other files if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I heard critical voices about Google Desktop who were concerning about data security and privacy....

Comment: Google Desktop Search has been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

xobni is a nice tool, I was using it but it takes lot of resources and I did not need so much features and all i wanted was better search, hence I found an other alternate Lookout, it works fine for me, also if you have installed google desktop, you can install the google plugin for outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Lookout - no longer officially offered or supported, but one of the best tools for this - requires a bit of work to get it to play nice with Outlook 2007/2010: http://www.wirwar.com/blog/2008/01/22/search-e-mail-at-lightspeed-using-lookout-with-outlook-2007/

Comment: Unfortunately not sure that it will work with latest versions of Windows 7 and Outlook 2010 anymore...seems to crash when indexing.